# Generate a shadow/outline uniformly around an element without the blur effect

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an element (let's say icon) with an irregular shape.

I want some kind of outline around it that conforms the shape in a certain color. The color of this outline must be uniformly around the shape, i.e. have the same distance from it everywhere and no color gradient.

What I found was using the css option `filter: drop-shadow()`

See: https://jsfiddle.net/m8w94qsz/3/

However, the generated shadow either has a blur effect (first example) or is not placed uniformly around the element (second example).

Is there any way to achieve the desired result with CSS?

Comment: Is it possible to have SVG code (vector) instead of pixelated images? That would make it allot easier.

Comment: Do you have an example how that could work if the icon was represented by an SVG vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `filter: url()` with an svg filter like so:

```css
svg{position:absolute; left:-10em;}
.my-icon {
  content: url('https://img.icons8.com/officel/344/arrow.png');
  filter: url('#outline');
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
<filter id="outline">
<feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" result="expanded"
operator="dilate" radius="3"/>
<feFlood flood-color="red" result="red" />
<feComposite in ="red" in2="expanded" operator="in" />
<feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
</svg>
<div>
  <i class="my-icon"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! Even though I was hoping for a more concise solution, this does indeed work!

Answer (score 2):

An interesting and useful answer @enxaneta inspired this answer

The examples below use a more complex set of filters.
But with this combination of filters, it becomes possible to adjust the thickness of the stroke, the presence or absence of a gap between the figure and the stroke.

- Icon stroke in red without a gap

Note the value of the `radius` attribute

```
      <feMorphology id="fm1" operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="5" result="e1" >
      </feMorphology>           
          <feMorphology id="fm2" operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                        radius="0.01" result="e2" > 
            </feMorphology>
```

```css
svg{position:absolute; left:-10em;}
.my-icon {
  content: url('https://img.icons8.com/officel/344/arrow.png');
  filter: url('#groupborder');
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
<defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-1%" y="-1%" width="360" height="360">
      <feMorphology id="fm1" operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="5" result="e1" >
      </feMorphology>   
    <feMorphology id="fm2" operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
      radius="0.01" result="e2" > 
   </feMorphology>    
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 1 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div>
  <i class="my-icon"></i>
</div>
```

- Changing the stroke thickness is achieved by changing the attribute
  `ralius =" 10 "`

```
<feMorphology id="fm1" operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="10" result="e1" >
```

```css
svg{position:absolute; left:-10em;}
.my-icon {
  content: url('https://img.icons8.com/officel/344/arrow.png');
  filter: url('#groupborder');
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
<defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-1%" y="-1%" width="360" height="360">
      <feMorphology id="fm1" operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="10" result="e1" >
      </feMorphology>   
    <feMorphology id="fm2" operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
      radius="0.01" result="e2" > 
   </feMorphology>    
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 1 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div>
  <i class="my-icon"></i>
</div>
```

- Stroke Icons with gap

```css
svg{position:absolute; left:-10em;}
.my-icon {
  content: url('https://img.icons8.com/officel/344/arrow.png');
  filter: url('#groupborder');
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
<defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-1%" y="-1%" width="360" height="360">
      <feMorphology id="fm1" operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="8" result="e1" >
      </feMorphology>   
    <feMorphology id="fm2" operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
      radius="4" result="e2" > 
   </feMorphology>    
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0.2 0
                             0 0 0 0.2 0
                             0 0 0 0.2 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div>
  <i class="my-icon"></i>
</div>
```

### Example animation

To draw attention to the icon, you can animate the stroke.

```
<feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="2" result="e2" > 
        <animate attributeName="radius" values="6;4;2;2;4;6" dur="1s" calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </feMorphology>
```

```css
svg{position:absolute; left:-10em;}
.my-icon {
  content: url('https://img.icons8.com/officel/344/arrow.png');
  filter: url('#groupborder');
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
<defs>
    <filter id="groupborder" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
            x="-20%" y="-20%" width="420" height="420">
      <feMorphology operator="erode" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="2" result="e1" >
   <animate attributeName="radius" values="2;4;6;6;4;2" dur="1s" calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </feMorphology>   
      <feMorphology operator="dilate" in="SourceAlpha"
                    radius="2" result="e2" > 
  <animate attributeName="radius" values="6;4;2;2;4;6" dur="1s" calcMode="discrete" repeatCount="indefinite" />
      </feMorphology>    
      <feComposite in="e1" in2="e2" operator="xor"
                   result="outline"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" in="outline"
                     values="0 0 0 0 0
                             0 0 0 0.2 0
                             0 0 0 0.2 0
                             0 0 0 1 0" result="outline2"/>
      <feComposite in="outline2" in2="SourceGraphic"
                   operator="over" result="output"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div>
  <i class="my-icon"></i>
</div>
```